# Prove there is a $g:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(g(b))=b$ for each $b\in B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow B$ is surjective, where $B$ is
>   finite. Prove there is a $g:B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(g(b))=b$
>   for each $b\in B$.

I'm given a hint to use induction on the cardinality of $B$. I'm not exactly sure how to go about the inductive step. 
The texts give the inductive hypothesis to be: for any onto function $f:C\rightarrow D$, where $|D|=n$ and $C\subset\mathbb{R}$, there is a suitable $g:D\rightarrow C$. However, I don't see why they suppose $C\subset\mathbb{R}$, and not just take $C$ to be $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your texts seem really weird. All those requirements are not necessary.

> Let $f : A \to B$ be surjective, where $A$ is any set and $B$ is countable. Then there exists $g : B \to A$ such that $f(g(b)) = b$ for each $b \in B$.

**Proof:** For each $b \in B$, choose $g(b)$ to be a preimage of $b$ under $f$, i.e. choose $g(b) \in \{x : f(x) = b\}$, where $\{x : f(x) = b\}$ is always nonempty by surjectivity of $f$. Now $g$ satisfies the requirements.

By the way, if we use the axiom of choice, we can do this construction for any sets $B$, not just countable ones.

Comment: Why is it unnecessary to use induction in this case?